# Upgraded iPad 2 to iOS 5 : no device summary pane

Tags: data-synchronization, ipad, itunes

I upgraded my iPad 2 to iOS 5.

I don't want to sync it through the cloud : I just want to sync it as usual, with iTunes through my USB connector.

But I have a problem : as soon as I upgradedto iOS 5, when my iPad is connected to my Mac, iTunes is not displaying the *device summary pane*.

I have SnowLeopard 10.6.8, iTunes 10.5.

Here is a screenshot of what I get :

[image: My iPad, connected to my Mac]

As you can see, the iPad is seen by iTunes, but no device summary pane is displayed.

Any idea how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you reboot both your Mac and your iPad already?

Comment: Yes, I did...but I still get the same problem. I also tried to restore my iPad. But that didn't change anything.

Comment: Is your iTunes updated to the newest version?

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I have iTunes 10.5, which, at the time of writing this question, the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution to my problem : I connected my iPad to another Mac, to check if I would face the same problem. It worked fine on the other machine.

Then, I tried to connect it again to my own Mac and to my great surprise, it was working perfectly !

So basically, connecting my iPad to another Mac solved the problem !